# Maximum number of fields in a single django model?

Tags: python, django

I am designing an app for the maritime industry. I am forced to add 62 float fields in a single Django model.

1. Would it make any problem with scalability?
2. is there any alternative better method?

#### [Edit]

Brief about application

This above-mentioned model is to hold the variables in a calculation. it is already connected to parent calculation, project etc. These variables are closely coupled with the business logic.

Database: PostgreSQL

Comment: This would most likely depend on your db backend. Both [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) and [postgres](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4302-0018-5%2F1.pdf) will have no issues with that number of columns per table. I would only split it into different tables if that made sense semantically.

Comment: Can you add more details about the columns and the dbms you are using?

Comment: Try to seperate the field in different tables. Like once I needed details of user, his physical details, social details, account details. I created five tables and joined them with Foreign key with a single User model. You can try something like that.

Comment: There's a similar question asked [here]
(https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/99174). Basically, it depends upon how you design your table. Do you have appropriate indexes? Do you query and fetch only a few columns frequently? Are you going to update data frequently? Have you considered NoSQL options?

Comment: I would really need to query and write to this model frequently. Indexing is not implemented.

Comment: @tomy you can create only one json field which can handle all your float field depending on how are you using these fields.

Comment: @NVS using JSON field is a good idea, since I am updating the model from firebase cloud function.